How to calculate properties of items in a class?
I need to calculate some properties for items in a class I have created called options.
I want to calculate the properties a few different ones overall but I do not want to use a for loop as I will have to calculate values for a specific one at any one time. The calculation changes, based on whether the Option.type instance attribute is either a "Call" or a "Put".
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["python", "-m", "venv", "trading_env"])
subprocess.run(["trading_env\\Scripts\\activate.bat"])
subprocess.run(["pip", "install", "numpy", "pandas", "matplotlib", "seaborn", "scipy"])
print("Python environment is complete with all the required packages installed.")

#import time data
from datetime import datetime
t = datetime.now()
print(t) # Example output: 2024-06-22 14:31:59.331225 

# creating a class for options (Object) 
class Option:
    def __init__(self, type, strike, expiry):
        self.type = type
        self.strike = strike
        self.expiry = expiry

# Creating an option
Option1 = Option('Call', 100, datetime(2024, 11, 15, 0, 0))
print(Option1.type)
print(Option1.strike)
print(Option1.expiry)  

#Inputs for BS Model
K = Option1.strike                     # K = Strike Price 
S = 100                                # S = Current Stock Price 
T = (Option1.expiry - t).days / 365.25 # T = Time to Expiration
r = 0.05                               # r = Risk free interest rate 5 %
D = 0                                  # D = Dividend Yield
sigma = 0.2                            # sigma = Volatility 20 %

print(f"{K:.3f}, {S:.3f}, {T:.3f}, {r:.3f}, {sigma:.3f}, {D:.3f}")

#importing the normal cumulative distribution function
from scipy.stats import norm 
import numpy as np

# calculating the option price using Black-Scholes
for i in range(len(Option)):
    if Option[i].type == 'Call':
        Option[i].price = (S*norm.cdf(d1) - K*norm.cdf(d2)*np.exp(-r*T))
        print(f"The Black Scholes Stock option price is: {Option_[i].price}")
    else:
        Option[i].price = (K*norm.cdf(-d2)*np.exp(-r*T) - S*norm.cdf(-d1))
        print(f"The Black Scholes Stock option price is: {Option_[i].price}")
    # calculating the options delta
    if Option[i].type == 'Call':
        Option[i].delta = np.exp(-D-(T))*norm.cdf(d1)
    else:
        Option[i].delta = -np.exp(-D-(T))*norm.cdf(-d1)
print(Option[i].delta)

From this code, when I run it, the Option-class and parameters are created and then the first option ( option1 ) is defined. When calculating the option price however, how do I reference just the specific one I want, without having to manually type out option1 or option2 every time?

Welcome to StackOverflow - you might reread the Code of Conduct and update your post so as to meet the Community policy of using MCVE / MRE formulated problem description. Your code is not C-omplete, is not R-eproducible and it takes awfully lot of reading through unrelated LOCs ( installing venv + pip installs  + many others ), that have no relation to R-eproduce the problem you try to solve. Repair your post so as to be a M-inimum yet C-omplete and R-eproducible E-xample of situation you wish to get solved, that is the Community way of cooperation here. That's fair, isn't it?
